# Select child records from tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I got the bellow piece of select statement that got level 2 child records, having problems to got deeper, can anyone help out?

```
SELECT
  id_mobile AS ID_PROJETO,
  UM.qtd_UC,
  AM.qtd_AMBIENTE
FROM projetos_mobile AS PM
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
      COUNT(id) AS qtd_UC,
      projeto,
      data_hora_importacao,
      id_uc_mobile
   FROM ucs_mobile
   WHERE data_hora_importacao = '2015-05-15 17:21:02'
   GROUP BY projeto) AS UM
ON PM.id_mobile = UM.projeto
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
      COUNT(id_uc_mobile) AS qtd_AMBIENTE,
      id_uc_mobile
   FROM ucs_mobile
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
         uc
      FROM ambientes_mobile AS s
      WHERE data_hora_importacao = '2015-05-15 17:21:02') AS G
   ON G.uc = ucs_mobile.id_uc_mobile
   WHERE data_hora_importacao = '2015-05-15 17:21:02') AS AM
ON UM.id_uc_mobile = AM.id_uc_mobile
WHERE PM.data_hora_importacao = '2015-05-15 17:21:02'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2eecf

here is a sqlfiddle if anyone want to try a solution. I have the specific hierarchy: projeto>uc>ambiente>secao>medicoes

```
ucs_mobile.projeto refers to projetos_mobile.id_mobile
ambientes_mobile.uc refers to ucs_mobile.id_uc_mobile
secoes_iluminacao_mobile.ambiente refers to ambientes_mobile.id_ambiente_mobile
```

I need a count of each child for the parent I pass, I will have 5 functions that 
return the count of each child for a given parent, for example, for a projeto parent I should have count(ucs),count(ambientes),count(secoes),count(medicoes)

So, hope you guys can help me. The database is terrible ugly but that's is what I got. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, but what are your expected results? Also, your default values should not be '0000-00-00' because that cannot be displayed properly. Try something like '0001-01-01'

Comment: I need a count of each child for the parent I pass, I will have 5 functions that 
return the count of each child for a given parent, for example, for a projeto parent I should have count(ucs),count(ambientes),count(secoes),count(medicoes)

Comment: Don't bother about the date, it was that way before I was working on it. But thanks for heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have really large queries like this, it can often be helpful to break them down individually, starting from the ground up and patching them together.

I started by just getting the count of each ucs_mobile row for each projetos_mobile value. You can do that by joining the two tables on the related row, and using `COUNT(DISTINCT um.id)` to get the number of rows. There are other ways to do it, but this particular method will scale better for the rest of your query:

```
SELECT pm.id, COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT um.id), 0) AS qty_uc
FROM projetos_mobile pm
LEFT JOIN ucs_mobile um ON um.data_hora_importacao = '2015-05-15 17:21:02' AND um.projeto = pm.id_mobile
GROUP BY pm.id;
```

The COALESCE function will be used to fill 0 counts. As long as you remember to use the `DISTINCT` keyword, and group by the proper `id`, you can just add in the child rows like so:

```
SELECT 
  pm.id, 
  COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT um.id), 0) AS qty_uc, 
  COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT am.id), 0) AS qty_am,
  COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT sim.id), 0) AS qty_sim
FROM projetos_mobile pm
LEFT JOIN ucs_mobile um ON um.data_hora_importacao = '2015-05-15 17:21:02' AND um.projeto = pm.id_mobile
LEFT JOIN ambientes_mobile am ON am.data_hora_importacao = um.data_hora_importacao AND am.uc = um.id_uc_mobile
LEFT JOIN secoes_iluminacao_mobile sim ON sim.data_hora_importacao = am.data_hora_importacao AND sim.ambiente = am.id_ambiente_mobile
GROUP BY pm.id;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dde0/1) example. **NOTE** I changed your sample data slightly to ensure my query was working as expected.

Also, a side note. I noticed as you went along that you kept using the same date in your `WHERE` clauses, so I just joined each table on the date as well, and made sure that in my very first join I looked for the date specified, which in turn will carry its way over to the other tables.

Comment: Great solution, it worked like a charm. You made it look so easy. Thank you for the help. 

It I'll be easy figure the counts for childs of childs now.